# php ext_skel_win32.php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to write some simple php extension on windows. Per tutorials, I need to use ext_skel_win32.php, but I don't find it in my php installation.

Where can I find this file? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you should have it, but here you are:

> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Y6ubk054